error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'QVector<Object>' {aka 'QList<Object>'} and 'QList<Object>')
I have Qt code that looks like following:
class test_gadget {
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(QString test MEMBER test)
public:
    QString test;
};

class test_gadget2 {
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(QVector<test_gadget> testo MEMBER testo)
public:
    QVector<test_gadget> testo;
};

class test_object : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVector<test_gadget2> gadget MEMBER gadget)
public:
    test_object(const test_gadget2& g);
private:
    QVector<test_gadget2> gadget;
};

However, when I tried to compile, it gives these errors
In file included from C:\Users\USER\source\repos\build-testqt2-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\apptestqt2_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp:2:
C:\Users\USER\source\repos\build-testqt2-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\apptestqt2_autogen\EWIEGA46WW/moc_test.cpp: In static member function 'static void test_gadget2::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)':
C:\Users\USER\source\repos\build-testqt2-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\apptestqt2_autogen\EWIEGA46WW/moc_test.cpp:211:27: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'QVector<test_gadget>' {aka 'QList<test_gadget>'} and 'QList<test_gadget>')
  211 |             if (_t->testo != *reinterpret_cast< QList<test_gadget>*>(_v)) {
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                     |        |
      |                     |        QList<[...]>
      |                     QList<[...]>
In file included from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qurl.h:11,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtQml/qqmlengine.h:7,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtQml/QQmlEngine:1,
                 from C:/Users/USER/source/repos/testqt2/test.hpp:2,
                 from C:\Users\USER\source\repos\build-testqt2-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\apptestqt2_autogen\EWIEGA46WW/moc_test.cpp:9,
                 from C:\Users\USER\source\repos\build-testqt2-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\apptestqt2_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp:2:
C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qlist.h:341:56: note: candidate: 'template<class U> QTypeTraits::compare_eq_result_container<QList<T>, U> QList<T>::operator!=(const QList<T>&) const [with U = U; T = test_gadget]'
  341 |     QTypeTraits::compare_eq_result_container<QList, U> operator!=(const QList &other) const
      |                                                        ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qlist.h:341:56: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++/bits/move.h:57,
                 from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++/utility:70,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qcompilerdetection.h:861,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qgenericatomic.h:8,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:8,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:8,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qatomic.h:8,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qrefcount.h:7,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:8,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qurl.h:8,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtQml/qqmlengine.h:7,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtQml/QQmlEngine:1,
                 from C:/Users/USER/source/repos/testqt2/test.hpp:2,
                 from C:\Users\USER\source\repos\build-testqt2-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\apptestqt2_autogen\EWIEGA46WW/moc_test.cpp:9,
                 from C:\Users\USER\source\repos\build-testqt2-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\apptestqt2_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp:2:
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++/type_traits: In substitution of 'template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = false; _Tp = bool]':
C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qtypeinfo.h:320:7:   required by substitution of 'template<class Container, class ... T> using compare_eq_result_container = std::enable_if_t<conjunction_v<std::disjunction<std::is_base_of<Container, T>, QTypeTraits::has_operator_equal<T> >...>, bool> [with Container = QList<test_gadget>; T = {test_gadget}]'
C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qlist.h:341:56:   required by substitution of 'template<class U> QTypeTraits::compare_eq_result_container<QList<test_gadget>, U> QList<test_gadget>::operator!=<U>(const QList<test_gadget>&) const [with U = test_gadget]'
C:\Users\USER\source\repos\build-testqt2-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\apptestqt2_autogen\EWIEGA46WW/moc_test.cpp:211:72:   required from here
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++/type_traits:2514:11: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, bool>'
 2514 |     using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\USER\source\repos\build-testqt2-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\apptestqt2_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp:2:
C:\Users\USER\source\repos\build-testqt2-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\apptestqt2_autogen\EWIEGA46WW/moc_test.cpp: In static member function 'static void test_object::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)':
C:\Users\USER\source\repos\build-testqt2-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\apptestqt2_autogen\EWIEGA46WW/moc_test.cpp:307:28: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'QVector<test_gadget2>' {aka 'QList<test_gadget2>'} and 'QList<test_gadget2>')
  307 |             if (_t->gadget != *reinterpret_cast< QList<test_gadget2>*>(_v)) {
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                     |         |
      |                     |         QList<[...]>
      |                     QList<[...]>
In file included from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qurl.h:11,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtQml/qqmlengine.h:7,
                 from C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtQml/QQmlEngine:1,
                 from C:/Users/USER/source/repos/testqt2/test.hpp:2,
                 from C:\Users\USER\source\repos\build-testqt2-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\apptestqt2_autogen\EWIEGA46WW/moc_test.cpp:9,
                 from C:\Users\USER\source\repos\build-testqt2-Desktop_Qt_6_6_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\apptestqt2_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp:2:
C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qlist.h:341:56: note: candidate: 'template<class U> QTypeTraits::compare_eq_result_container<QList<T>, U> QList<T>::operator!=(const QList<T>&) const [with U = U; T = test_gadget2]'
  341 |     QTypeTraits::compare_eq_result_container<QList, U> operator!=(const QList &other) const
      |                                                        ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qlist.h:341:56: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\apptestqt2.dir\build.make:129: CMakeFiles/apptestqt2.dir/apptestqt2_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:98: CMakeFiles/apptestqt2.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:135: all] Error 2
13:50:07: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin\cmake.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project testqt2 (kit: Desktop Qt 6.6.0 MinGW 64-bit)
When executing step "Build"

So I tried adding operator!= to every object so it looks like following:
class test_gadget {
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(QString test MEMBER test)
public:
    QString test;
    bool operator!=(const test_gadget& other) const {
        return this->test != other.test;
    }
};

class test_gadget2 {
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(QVector<test_gadget> testo MEMBER testo)
public:
    QVector<test_gadget> testo;
    bool operator!=(const test_gadget2& other) const {
        // error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'QVector<test_gadget>' {aka 'QList<test_gadget>'} and 'QList<test_gadget>')
        return this->testo != other.testo;
    }
};

class test_object : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVector<test_gadget2> gadget MEMBER gadget)
public:
    test_object(const test_gadget2& g);
private:
    QVector<test_gadget2> gadget;
};

However, the issues persist. How should I fix this issue?

Given QTypeTraits::has_operator_equal<T> and T = {test_gadget} in the error message I would try adding operator== to test_gadget.

@john Thanks a lot, it worked after adding operator==. Does this mean I would need to have both operator!= and operator== for every Q_GADGET? If yes, are there any ways I can make those functions better?

I have no specific knowledge of QT but in C++ if you have defined operator== you get operator!= generated (i.e. you get it for free) since C++20. Prior to that you should add both. Also from C++20 you can get a default version of operator== like this bool operator==(const test_gadget& other) const = default; but again how that works specifically with QT classes IDK.

@user1558325 Of course operator!= should always be written something like bool operator!=(const test_gadget& other) const { return !(*this == other); }

@john I see how it is, thanks a lot
